# Highchart boxplot zones use median instead of high as threshold

Tags: javascript, highcharts, boxplot

I want to create a boxplot chart with zones using Highcharts. It seems that highchart uses the high value as threshold.
Does anyone know if it is possible to change that to use the median for example ?

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-boxplot-zones

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Well, the chart renders exactly as you instruct it.

```
760, 801, 848, 895, 1265
```

If you want a different chart you would change the variables. In each case, the chart is rendering boxplots according to your data.

Comment: Indeed, but my question is about the zones : I want to know if there is a way to use the median value instead of the high value as threshold for the zones

Comment: Well, you also specify a value in the zones options, this should reflect the median value instead of the high.

Comment: Yes but it won't work since highchart uses the high value.

Comment: I understand. I think the answer is no. But it is just an SVG, so after it has rendered you can just find the correct part of the SVG and change the colour based on the median value. A bit hacky (i know) but I think it is what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

It is not officially supported, but you can set `zoneAxis` for example to `'median'`:

```
series: [{
  data: [ // low, q1, median, q3, high
    ...
  ],
  ...,
  zoneAxis: 'median'
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/5001/

**API Reference:**  https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.boxplot.zoneAxis